# How do I display different error messages using jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

I am trying to add validation to my form with jQuery Validation Plugin, but I'm having a problem where the plugin puts the same error messages `Please enter a valid URL.`

**My code:**http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3124/

Any solution for that?

Thanks

Comment: Please also specify what you yourself have tried to solve your problem. Give us a scope of where you think (or have analyzed) that the problem may be.

Comment: You have bypassed the posting rules by including a jsFiddle link without any code in the OP.

Comment: Where does _"Please enter a valid URL"_ have to do with anything in your code?

Comment: @Sparky I hope I didn't touch a nerve there ! And sorry but the question has been answered ! Thanks :)

Comment: It doesn't matter that it was already answered.  StackOverflow is not about _you_ getting what you want; it's about maintaining a repository of higher quality questions and answers that will help _everyone_.  Your question is unlikely to help future readers.   [It should be edited so that it makes sense and follows the posting rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), or it should be closed... that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sparky already pointed out you used the wrong selector.

If your problem is that the same error message is displayed in every field, you can specify what error message is displayed specifically for each field, for example:

```
$('#install').validate({
        rules: {
            title: {
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 15,
                required: true
            }
    },
    messages:{ title: {
        required: "Custom message for required rule",
        maxlength: "Another custom message"
    }}
...
```

You can also control where the error messages are displayed, for example by using the errorLabelContainer and errorElement options in validate. See doc [**here**](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate):

> Use errorClass, errorElement, wrapper, errorLabelContainer,
>   errorContainer, showErrors, success, errorPlacement, highlight,
>   unhighlight, and ignoreTitle to control how invalid elements and error
>   messages are displayed.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what he means.  Quoting the OP...  _"the plugin outputs the same error message, 'Please enter a valid URL.'"_   That message has nothing to do with his code since he's not even using the URL rule, nor could the plugin have been working with the broken selector.  The question was very lazily written and yet it's still rewarded with an up-vote.  (see edit history).

Comment: @Sparky I misunderstood because I only looked at your fiddle

Comment: Not your fault. I tried, but it's not worth salvaging.  At worst, it's nonsense.  At best, it's a duplicate question that's been answered dozens of times already.

Answer (score 1):

`'install'` is not a valid jQuery selector:

```
$('install').validate({...
```

You are targeting `id="install"` so you need a hash:

```
$('#install').validate({...
```

Your jsFiddle demo is working now:

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3129/

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"I'm having a problem where the plugin puts the same error messages 'Please enter a valid URL'."*

No idea what you're talking about since there is nothing in your code that has anything to do with validating a URL.  You need to fix your question by posting the relevant code and clearly explaining what you expect this code to do.

Comment: @user3350731,  That's exactly how it's supposed to work!  What are you expecting?